# How can I increase number by one only when the loop is over?

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am trying to increase number by one only when the loop is over and then I want to active this loop again with the new number that increased by one.

```
for l in range(len(listc)):
  n+=1
  for item in new['stuff']:
   c+=1
   try:
    st = item[list1[c]]
    if org[c].startswith(listc[n]):
        byte += len(item["In"]+"1234")
        print(len(item["In"]+"1234"))
        if listc[c] == sorted_listc[1]:
            listc[c] = org[c][0:len(common)+1]
        print(hex(byte))
    else:
        pass


   except:
       continue
```

I want that every time the loop of the new['stuff'] is over, n will increase by one.
Somehow it doesn't work, any help?

Comment: There are more kinds of loops than for loops

Comment: @bryan60 Oh ok. Do you have some solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As you code presented you are increasing the value on `n` by before the inner loop (over the `new['stuff']`) starts.

Try to pass the increase to the end of the inner loop.

```
n = 0
for l in range(len(listc)):
    for item in new['stuff']:
        ### do stuff
    n += 1
```

You can also try and use the [Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop **terminates through exhaustion** of the iterable.

For example:

```
n = 0
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 3):
        print(i*j)
    else:
        n += 1
```

Will results with:

```
1
2
2
4
3
6
4
8
>>> print(n)
4
```